# When does the instruction pointer point to zero?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel-module

The instruction pointer points to the next instruction to be executed. But what under what condition does it point to zero and what are the implications?

Comment: It points to zero if you set it to zero (e.g. by jumping) or if it wraps around. The implication is that cpu will execute whatever is at address zero (same as always). Other than that, you need to provide more details.

Comment: Do you mean 'point at zero' or 'loaded with zero'?  Either way, the circumstances and implications are architecture-dependent.

Comment: On some architectures it might cause CPU fault (an exception), on others something like `jmp $0`, means executing instructions from that address. Some architectures may even not have that address space mapped or available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stack corruption:
   The ret instruction pops the address from the stack into EIP register. When the stack  is corrupted (due to overrun maybe), it might cause EIP to be set to zero.
2. Using direct jump to zero